# jquery Isotope how to fix container height to 100% with overflow: auto

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-isotope

In Isotope 2.0, I want the elements container to have fix 100% height with overflow: auto, however, when the layout is complete it keeps changing the height of the container to absolute pixels (thus no scroll in the container).

There is no longer the "resizesContainer : false" in Isotope 2.0.

Here's what I have so far:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var $container = $('#content');

    $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
        $container.isotope({
            filter : '*',
            layoutMode : 'masonry',
            // itemSelector: ".boxportfolio3",
            resizesContainer : false,
            containerStyle : {
                overflow : 'auto',
            },
            animationOptions : {
                duration : 750,
                easing : 'linear',
                queue : false,
            }
        });

        $container.isotope('on', 'layoutComplete', function(a,b) {
            console.log("this is not executed. why?? ");
            $(".isotope").css("height", "100%");
        });



    });
});
```

Answer (score 5):

It turned out that the "!important" tag solved the issue:

```
.isotope {
    height: 100% !important;
}
```